# Svelte reactivity: todos.forEach(todo => todo.completed = completed) vs. todos.forEach((todo, i) => todos[i].completed = completed)

Tags: svelte

I'm working on the [MDN svelte tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_getting_started) and in this section on the `checkAllTodos` function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_reactivity_lifecycle_accessibility#reactivity_gotchas_updating_objects_and_arrays

it states that,

`todos.forEach(todo => todo.completed = completed)`does not trigger reactivity but `todos.forEach((todo, i) => todos[i].completed = completed)` does, because

> assignments to properties of arrays and objects work the same way as assignments to the values themselves

I understand why `todos.forEach(todo => todo.completed = completed)`does not do the trick, but don't see why `todos.forEach((todo, i) => todos[i].completed = completed)` does. Why do assignments to properties of arrays and objects work the same way as assignments to the values themselves?

For me, both should fail to trigger reactivity as they do not change the reference of todos.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

This is called "conservative reactivity": The compiler will invalidate a variable when it or any of its properties (or more deeply nested properties) are assigned. Otherwise it would be hard to impossible to track all changes correctly, especially through component props.